# RAILS: safe parameterization of user input in Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection, arel

So before anyone beats the hell out of me, I know how to do this when calling Arel methods. What I'm curious about is if there is a way to simply get that sql injection safe version of the user input so I have it in hand and can do what I want with it.

Ideally I'd be interested in something along the lines of:

```
safe_input_data = Person.sql_safe params[:user_data_for_arel_manipulation]
```

I spent some time last night looking for something that would do this but found nothing. I read all the ActiveRecord methods, but there is jack in the way of documentation. Going simply by the method names and the source of those methods I didn't see anything. I'm hoping someone knows of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you an sql safe string:

```
safe_input_data = Person.sanitize(params[:user_data_for_arel_manipulation])
```

Be aware, it also adds single quotes to your string!

So `"my unsafe input"` becomes `"'my unsafe input'"`.